# Cleaning up memory after loading Access DB into a datagrid

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-optimization, .net-datatable

I wrote an app that pulls a MS Access DB into a `DataTable` and then displays it into a WPF datagrid. The dialog window has a search button which calls on a class that does the DB work.

The methods in play of the search window:

```
private void ExitBtn_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    quoteheaders.Dispose();
    GC.Collect();
    Close();
}
private void TitleBar_DblClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Normal) { this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized; return; }
    if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized) { this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal; return; }
}
private void TitleBar_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left) { DragMove(); }
}
private Task<DataTable> Poll_QuoteHeader()
{
    return Task.Run(() => SQLinterface.FindQuoteID(dbPath));
}
private async void SearchBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    quoteheaders = SQLinterface.FindQuoteID(dbPath);
    quoteheaders = await Poll_QuoteHeader();
    foundQuotes.ItemsSource = quoteheaders.AsDataView();
}
```

The class that talks to the database:

```
namespace QuoteClient
{
    class SQLinterface
    {
    public DataTable FindServer()
    {
        DataTable SQLservers = new DataTable();
        SqlDataSourceEnumerator SQLinstances = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
        SQLservers = SQLinstances.GetDataSources();
        return SQLservers; 
    }
    public DataTable FindQuoteID(string dbPath)
    {
        using(DataTable quoteID = new DataTable())
            {
            using (OleDbConnection quoteIDconn = new OleDbConnection(dbPath))
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter quoteIDadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM DocumentHeaders", quoteIDconn);
                quoteIDadapter.Fill(quoteID);
                return quoteID;
            } 
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm bringing this here because I would like to know if it is OK to use `GC.Collect()` in this case. The app works fine without forcing a collection, but increases in memory every time the window is opened and search button is clicked. I am undecided on whether this is an actual leak or just the GC taking its time to cleanup.

So in short is there a better way to ensure that the memory that is used for filling the data table is disposed of? (I dispose of them either via `using` or `.Dispose()` )

Should I just leave the collection call since I know that when this window is closed nothing that was in use is needed anymore?

Or am I doing something wrong all around?

Comment: Please use MVVM for developing WPF apps. You should avoid setting `ItemsSource` in code-behind.

Comment: Duly noted, I just have not progressed to the point of MVVM. I'm still trying to experiment and understand WPF itself. Setting the `ItemSource` in code behind  is not related to the memory usage I am seeing and learning how to handle. It happens when I do not show the data but only load it into a `DataTable`

Comment: Are you sure this is working code? Why would you return a `quoteID` that you dispose with a `using`. This does not make any sense.

Comment: It gets returned to another `DataTable`. It works. I suppose thats an improvement i can make to just use the first one, but i had trouble getting it to work properly with the asynchronous `Task <DataTable> `method

Comment: As per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18869167/220986) - calling `Dispose` doesn't actually do much for `DataTable.`. Also @t3chb0t is right: you dispose of the `quoteID` when you return from `FindQuoteID` - that's wrong. It happens to work because `Dispose` doesn't do much for `DataTable` but it's still wrong to do it. And you can't "free" memory in C#. The `Dispose` pattern in C# primarily exists to release unmanaged resources and not to release memory. There are very very few situations in which calling `GC.Collect()` might make sense but I don't think this is one of them.